# How to insert data from PHP server to another running PHP / MySql?

Tags: php, web-services, remote-server

My English is bad. please understand.

I have a plan to make a website which provides Hotel booking API?!.

What i think right now are following...

1. I have a JAVA based web-server and MySql DB server.
2. My client would mostly be small hotel's or motel's owner with their own website based on PHP web-server.
3. The final client which means the hotel guests would visit the hotels' website to make reservation.
4. But they do not have a fine reservation system on the websites.
5. So, I'd like to provides the reservation system for easier booking for free.
6. However, all the reservation records would be saved in my MySql DB Server.

Here's my question. How could Remote PHP server insert reservation data into my remote MySql DB Server without knowing the ID/PW and allowed and opened port for external user?
And, Which technologies do I need?

I am going to study what I need!! thank you.

Comment: API means there's a service running in front of your database which accepts requests (typically standard HTTP requests) and works on them. It's not much different from websites and forms, just without the website. This can be done in virtually any programming language. Clients do *not* connect directly to the database and talk SQL to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way - webservices.

Implement web-service with authentication on the database server and implement web-service client on the servers which need to connect to this database. You won't provide login-password to the MySQL database. You will provide login-password for your implemented web-service.

So, take a look at web-services technology. It is easy to understand and implement.

Comment: oh thanks! I have basic knowledge of java and php. and Next! web-services. cheers!~